# How to use tooltip in a for loop

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

This is the code in the blade file. What I'm trying to do is to display the remaining text of description when the user hovers the mouse on "Hover for full details" however it just repeats the firs value of the first appointment's description.

```
@foreach ($appointments as $appointment)
      <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
          Subject: <b>{{ Str::limit($appointment->subject,20,"...") }}</b>  <br>Description: <b>{{Str::limit($appointment->description,10,"...")}}</a></b>
          <span data-tooltip-target="tooltip-default" class="text-xs font-semibold inline-block py-1 px-2 uppercase rounded-full text-cyan-600 bg-cyan-200 uppercase last:mr-0 mr-1">>Hover for full Details</span>
          <div id="tooltip-default"  role="tooltip" class="inline-block absolute invisible z-10 py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 rounded-lg shadow-sm opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-300 tooltip dark:bg-gray-700">
             {{$appointment->description}}
             <div class="tooltip-arrow" data-popper-arrow></div>
          </div>
      </td>
```

This is what I have. It repeats the description of the first record
[image]

Comment: From your image above, I cannot see any repitition.

Comment: It just repeats the same description "po un te norvus" on all the rows when hovering the mouse on the blue text

Comment: But I am seeing ```1. po un te n...```  ```2. anchora``` Check your image

Comment: So you mean that if you hover on the second client's description, it changes from ```anchora``` to ```po un te n...``` ?

Comment: you can create new array for tooltip mapping it with appointment array index and store `description` for each index and in blade just call it `$tooltip[$key]['description'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case **data-tooltip-target** and **Id of the target** are not unique. This should solve your problem:

```
@foreach ($appointments as $appointment)
  <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
      Subject: <b>{{ Str::limit($appointment->subject,20,"...") }}</b>  <br>Description: <b>{{Str::limit($appointment->description,10,"...")}}</a></b>
      <span data-tooltip-target="{{'tooltip-default-'. $appointment->id}}" class="text-xs font-semibold inline-block py-1 px-2 uppercase rounded-full text-cyan-600 bg-cyan-200 uppercase last:mr-0 mr-1">>Hover for full Details</span>
      <div id="{{'tooltip-default-'. $appointment->id}}"  role="tooltip" class="inline-block absolute invisible z-10 py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 rounded-lg shadow-sm opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-300 tooltip dark:bg-gray-700">
         {{$appointment->description}}
         <div class="tooltip-arrow" data-popper-arrow></div>
      </div>
  </td>
```